# ubuntu on my new smartphone as substitute for android?!

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want ubuntu on my new galaxy s4 NOW :-) -- I don't like android very much ...I'd be really glad to stop this android thing on my very expensive phone! Would somebody be so kind to tell me about the progress in the ubuntu for phones project ... Should I make a try ...??! Thank you in advance ...( I am unexperienced user with android but I know the advantages of linux-ubuntu quite well !! : ) Best wishes to canonical from germany!

Comment: Still in development i would wait.

Answer (score 1):

*Ubuntu Touch* is currently in development.

As said in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install, stable releases are only for

> Google's LG Nexus 4
>
> Google's Samsung Galaxy Nexus

You can see on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices that you can build Ubuntu Touch for Samsung Galaxy S4, but :

1. Sound is broken
2. Camera is broken
3. Cellular radio (call/sms) is broken
4. Frequent freezes and random reboots occur.

So you could **try** Ubuntu Touch, but certainly not use it on daily bases.

Comment: after announcing ubuntu for phones almost one year ago ...where do we get information about developments then ...

Comment: Informations : http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ and http://forum.xda-developers.com .

Ubuntu Touch was announced for "Nexus" devices since day 1. Other smartphones are not backed by Cannonical and are developed only by fan-developers.